# How to display timezone offset in dropdown

Tags: javascript, momentjs, timezone-offset

I have a dropdown of list of countries. When I select a country I load the list of timezones in a separate dropdown below.[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZISYJ.png)

I need to display the UTC offset alongside the timezone region. How do I use moment.timezone in javascript to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can do something like this:

If you want to get the offset at a certain date to account for daylight savings time:

```
var zone = moment.tz.zone('America/New_York');
zone.parse(Date.UTC(2012, 2, 19, 8, 30)); // 240 (minutes)
```

If you want to get the offset of a timezone given a UTC timestamp:

```
moment.tz.zone('America/Los_Angeles').offset(1388563200000); // 480
```

Source: http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/parse/